# WooCommerce Apply Coupon to order AFTER taxes

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have a product that costs 1000 (incl taxes). Then I apply a coupon code for 10%, but then the amount is 920.

It is supposed to be 900 (eg. 100 in discount).

I am applying the code programatically like so:

```
$order->apply_coupon('123')
```

It seems like the discount is being applied in the product price WITHOUT taxes, but it ought to be applied INCLUDING taxes.

The general taxes is 25%, but all product prices are set including taxes.

So if you do 1000 - 20% (the taxes) its: 800, and 10% of 800 is 80, hence the discount being only 80, where in reality it ought to be 100.

Could anybody help me out here? If I apply the coupon using the normal checkout flow, it works fine, but I am trying to apply a coupon programmatically.

Comment: I don't have a solution at hand, but your diagnosis of the problem is not correct. The 20% tax on a product that costs $1000 is not $200. That's not how percentages work. A $1000 product including 20% tax is $833.33 before tax (120% of $833.33 is $1000), and 10% of $833.33 is not exactly $80, so that can't be the cause of your problem. Are the numbers in your question the exact numbers you're testing in your code?

Comment: hi @JacobPeattie and thanks for your interest. As the issue was primarily around applying discounts AFTER taxes, instead of BEFORE taxes, I choose to simplify the question, to avoid any confusion. Actually, the tax is 25% in Denmark, where I'm from, so you'll have to do - 20% if you wish to remove the taxes again. Anyways, thanks for ensuring that we're both on track.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently came across this problem as well and managed to fix it.

In my case I created the order and added the line items and coupons programatically. When this is done, you calculate the totals and taxes. If there was no coupon to apply I would use: `$order->calculate_totals( true )` and when a coupon was applied I did not use the calculate_totals method since `$order->apply_coupons` [recalculates the totals and taxes automatically](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5d7f6acbcb387f1d51d51305bf949d07fa3c4b08/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-order.php#L1158).

Doing this for percentage based coupons, the calculation went wrong and the total amount did not match the amount I was expecting. And like you, the calculation would be correct when following the normal checkout flow.

So what I did was calculate the totals after the line items were added and before the coupon was applied. This ensures that the taxes and totals were correct before the coupon was applied.

Simplified example:

```php
// Create a new order.
$order = new WC_Order();
$order->set_prices_include_tax( true );
$order_id = $order->save();

// Add line item for order.
$line_item = new WC_Order_Item_Product();
$line_item->set_order_id( $order_id );
$line_item->set_name( 'Test product' );
$line_item->set_quantity( 1 );
$line_item->set_tax_class( 'tax-21' );
$line_item->set_subtotal( 1000 / 1.21 ); // Calc price pre tax: 21% VAT in this case.
$line_item->set_total( 1000 / 1.21 );
$line_item_id = $line_item->save();

// The next line is what fixed the problem: 
// Calculate totals and taxes before a coupon is applied to ensure taxes and totals for order are correct.
$order->calculate_totals( true ); 

// Apply coupon.
$order->apply_coupon( 'MY_COUPON_CODE' );
```