# Apply coupon after taxes on woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have a woocommerce website where prices are configured and displayed without taxes, it is usings coupons but the coupon value is applied to the total before taxes on the checkout and I would like to apply it after the taxes are added to the order. [This thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/365386/woocommerce-apply-coupon-to-order-after-taxes) is doing that but programitacaly and i would like to do it when a user add a coupon